# Where do the roots lie on argand plane?

Tags: complex-numbers, analytic-geometry

If the roots of $(z-1)^n = i(z+1)^n$  are plotted on the argand plane they are

A. On a parabola

B. Noncyclic

C. Collinear

D. The Vertices of a triangle

I solved as far as getting the nth root of $i =\frac{z-1}{z+1}$. And I thought as the roots would lie on a circle of mod 1 hence the answer must be a circle. But there is no option. Please help. And also suggest what's wrong in my approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take the absolute value on both sides of the equation:$$|(z-1)^n|=|i(z+1)^n|$$
$$|(z-1)^n|=|(z+1)^n|\cdot|i|$$
$$|z-1|^n=|z+1|^n$$
$$|z-1|=|z+1|$$
That last equation implies that $z$ must lie on the imaginary axis.

Comment: What's wrong in my approach ?

Comment: @Tejus to be honest I don't really understand what you did. You say "I thought as the roots would lie on a circle of mod 1...". What makes you think that the roots are on a circle of mod 1?